# Find the max price in JSON

Tags: json, python-3.x, for-loop

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://graphs2.coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/"
r = requests.get(url)
cont = r.json()
print(cont)

maxPrice = 0
for item in cont["price_btc"]:
    if(item[1] > maxPrice):
        maxPrice = (item[1])

print (maxPrice)
```

In my code, I am trying to find the max price in "price_btc" from a JSON file (in the file, each item in "price_btc" is [amount, price]). When I run my code, it prints out 1.0, which isn't the right value.

Comment: Can you give the first few lines of output for print(cont)

Comment: What value were you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

Looks at https://graphs2.coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/ and doing a quick look at specifically the "price_btc" property, then all the [amount, price] values, all price values appear to be 1.

Comment: I just realized that I confused the contents of "price_usd" with "price_btc" Thank you for your help!

Comment: Mark as answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think than you are taking always `item[1]` and you have to look `item[0]`.

Look the array: `"price_btc": [[1367174841000, 1.0], [1367261101000, 1.0]...]`

Always 1.0 it will be more bigger than `maxPrice = 0`

Greetings!